# LARAVEL How to get ID value on Auto Increment ID for naming file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to renaming uploaded file to same as ID of table Slider for unique name

```
public function postAddSlider(){
    $title = Input::get('title');
    $image = Input::file('image');
    $link = Input::get('link');
    $description = Input::get('description');

    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName(); //<-- i want to change that filename to be id of table Slider
    $uploadSuccess = Input::file('image')->move(base_path().'/public/assets/slider/', $filename);

    if($uploadSuccess){
        $slider = Slider::create(array(
            'image' =>  $uploadSuccess->getRealPath(),
            'title' => $title,
            'link' => $link,
            'description' => $description
        ));

        if($slider){
            return Redirect::route('slider-add-get')
                    ->with('message','Slider Added Successfully');
        }
    }
    else{
        return Redirect::route('slider-add-get')
                ->with('message','File Upload Error');
    }
}
```

or do you have other solution to renaming for unique name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you're schema is like, but if you want to get the id of a model, you have to save it first.

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
$slide = new Slide();
$slide->title = Input::get('title');
$slide->url = $temporaryurl;
...etc...
$slide->save();

//once the slide is saved, we can access its id
$slide->url = 'slide-' . $slide->id . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$slide->save(); //updates the new url
```

Or, if you're just looking to generate unique file names, you could use the original filename + the timestamp... Could possibly result in duplicates... very unlikely though (that 2 images would be uploaded with the same filename within the same second).

Or, perhaps, the slide title (stripped of illegal characters, spaces replaced with dashes, etc), plus the timestamp.

Comment: thanks it works :D
i dont know i can access its id after save

Comment: @GandhyOnly Glad to help. If you require any more clarification please comment on it. Otherwise I'd appreciate you accepting this answer :)